# select with name attribute is not getting sent to server

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

i have this select element

```
<label for = "consumer" class = "m-b-10" >Consumer Group</label >
<select class = "form-control" id = "consumer" name = "consumer_group"  >
   <option value = "1" data-group = "Men" >Men</option >
   <option value = "2" data-group = "Women" >Women </option >
   <option value = "3" data-group = "Unisex" >Unisex </option >
   <option value = "4" data-group = "Children" >Children</option >
</select >
```

with this when i submit the form  , consumer_group is not sent to the server , 
however if i remove the id attribute i do receive the value  .

---

i would like to know what causes this? , 
does select elements prevent having an id attribute?

Comment: [`select` is not broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips) (pun intended). That `select` *will* get sent to the server, regardless of an `id` attribute, barring something else in your code preventing it -- by making it `disabled`, removing it, etc. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: I should note, though, that Stack Snippets don't support forms (not even ones with `target="_blank"`, so you probably can't do a Stack Snippet for this...

Comment: something else would be javascript code , i did change the id attribute to anything as well to check if there is a selector preventing it ,  but the problem is still up  , removing the id will send it 

also i did check for duplicate name attributes there were none ,  

note : im using jquery validation plugin , could it be a reason?

Comment: `note : im using jquery validation plugin , could it be a reason? `  Absolutely. I would start there